# Pre-increment in recursive call

Tags: java, recursion, pre-increment

I was solving this leetcode question https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-right-side-view/description/ .

The following code works correctly.

```
class Solution {
    public List<Integer> rightSideView(TreeNode root) {
        List <Integer> ans = new LinkedList<>();
        if (root == null) return ans;
        traverse(root, ans, 0);
        return ans;
    }

    public void traverse(TreeNode root, List<Integer> ans, int currDepth){
        if (root == null) return;

        if (ans.size() == currDepth) ans.add(root.val);
        traverse(root.right, ans, currDepth + 1);
        traverse(root.left, ans, currDepth + 1);
    }
}
```

However, during the last 2 recursive calls, if I change the lines to

```
 traverse(root.right, ans, ++currDepth);
 traverse(root.left, ans, ++currDepth);
```

the code fails, why does this happen? Shouldn't both versions be equivalent?

Comment: What do you think `++currDepth` does?

Comment: increase the given value of currDepth by one before the recursive call finishes?
As opposed to currDepth++ which would increase it afterwards

Comment: Great. Now what's the value of `currDepth` when used as an argument in the second invocation of `traverse` if the first increased it by one?

Comment: Well, 2, right?
It started as 0, first call increased it to 1, so during the 2nd call it should be 2

Comment: Right. Did the you expect the same thing to happen when you used `currDept + 1`?

Comment: Yes, I did expect that

Comment: You expected `currDept + 1` to increase the value stored in `currDept`? Then that's where your misunderstanding is. The `+` operator does not modify its operands.

Comment: I mean, I know it wouldn't increase it during the current call, but rather on the next one, the one being called.
Do you mean that using currDepth + 1 with an initial value of currDepth = 0 not make the value of currDepth = 1 in the next call?

Comment: Yes, I mean that two consecutive `currDepth + 1` expressions will result in the same value, whereas two consecutive `currDepth++` expressions will result in two different values.

Comment: Note that recursion has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Ahh, now I see the error, this seems kinda dumb now haha, thanks.

Comment: calling "currdept + 1" will not change the values of currdepth (which is what you want); calling ++currDepth will change the values of currDepth (which is what you do not want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say currDepth = 0

In your first version, the two recursive calls will look like this:

```
traverse(root.right, ans, 1);
traverse(root.left, ans, 1);
```

This is correct because you want both recursive calls to go to the next level.

In your second version, it looks like this:

```
traverse(root.right, ans, 1);
traverse(root.left, ans, 2);
```

This means the first recursive call works fine, but the second one is wrong (skips one level).

Why? you **changed** your `currDepth` parameter. The first version of your code doesn't change it. It passes `currDepth + 1` to the next level.

Comment: Thank you, I now see what went wrong, I forgot that using ++currDepth would change the value on the next line.